# What is the best way to install python 3.7.7 as a user (locally) without sudo or wget?

Tags: python, python-install

I'm trying to install python3.7.7 on a remote server (Mac OS X). However, I have no `sudo` privileges nor I can use `wget` command. Would someone know the best way to install this python version and pip3 only for me as a user, locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [the installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this: `installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /` but it says `installer: Must be run as root to install this package.` any ideas how I could install it? :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the same step written in this [page](http://thelazylog.com/install-python-as-local-user-on-linux/). Remember to use the correct version with 3.7.7 instead of 2.7 (hence use this link in the wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/Python-3.7.7.tgz)

Comment: I've tried to follow the instruction on the page you shared but when I did `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-3.7.7.tgz`
 then I received `-bash: wget: command not found`. Any hint how could I solve this? thanks!

Comment: You should install `wget` as well but since it is the issue, probably the best way would be to download the python archive manually from the site and then transfer the tar.gz to your remote host in your home folder. Then you simply skip the `wget` line in the linked page